# Why WCF async method doesn't throw a FaultException when a sync do?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, task

I've made some tests with WCF, and I'm not sure to understand one thing.

I've the following service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICommunicationIssuesService:IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void TestExceptionInActionSync();
    [OperationContract]
    Task TestExceptionInActionAsync();
}
```

with the following implementation:

```
public class CommunicationIssuesService :  ICommunicationIssuesService
{
    public void TestExceptionInActionSync()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public async Task TestExceptionInActionAsync()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

On the client side, I create a ChannelFactory, then on it:

```
//Test Synchronous
//... Setup of the channelFactory
ICommunicationIssuesService channel =_channelFactory.CreateChannel()
try{
    channel.TestExceptionInActionSync();
}catch(FaultException<ExceptionDetail>){
    //I receive an FaultException
}

//Test Asynchronous
//... Setup of the channelFactory
ICommunicationIssuesService channel =_channelFactory.CreateChannel()
try{
    channel.TestExceptionInActionAsync();
}catch(AggregateException){
    //I receive an AggregateException, I guess because it's a Task behind   
}
```

What I don't understand is why I don't receive a FaultException(or an AggregateException) here?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is by design in the `Async APIs`, you need to access the returned Task using `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait`, to get the exception, since this is an Async implementation therefore `await Task` will also do. The calls mentioned above `Wait`, `Result`, `await` helps in unwrapping the exception in the Task as they try to access the Task status, which is `Faulted` for the exception and try to access the Result, if any or may be just wait for completion, even if it has exception, check [Task Status](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/08/30/the-meaning-of-taskstatus/)

Modify the your code as follows:

`await channel.TestExceptionInActionAsync();`